# UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end

Tags: unity-game-engine, syntax-error, unityscript

I'm trying to make a GUI.DrawTexture that clickable, but the error said "Assets/Script/guisettingonmenu.js(46,13): UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end."
Can someone please help me?

```
//make it clickable
Rect onButton = new Rect(640, 250, 80, 40);
GUI.DrawTexture(onButton, onNormal);
if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
    if (onButton.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition)){
        GUI.DrawTexture(onButton, onHover);
    }
}
```

Comment: what line is that error message pointing at? Keep in mind that sometimes syntax errors can be triggered by a syntax issue several lines earlier than where the compiler says the issue is.

Comment: it was in the row 46, which is contain
`Rect onButton = new Rect(640, 250, 80, 40);`

Comment: new Rect() looks like C# ... check if that is valid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup that is a c# syntax  in js is goes

```
var onButton : Rect = new Rect(640, 250, 80, 40);
```

Comment: yup, i just realized it. Thanks :D